# Emacs freezes when running Julia

Tags: emacs, ess, julia

I would like to run the Julia REPL inside Emacs, but sadly emacs get frozen when I do so (whether I run from an emacs shell or from ESS run-julia). Does somebody has/had this problem, and if so how did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no run-julia in ESS. Use M-x julia. Your `inferior-julia-program-name` should point to your `julia-basic`. If you have `julia-basic` in your path, it should work by default.

To diagnose any problem, `M-x julia` and then go to `*julia*` buffer and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. Thanks a lot. Out of interest, how did you know about julia-basic?

Comment: @S4M Because I added julia support to ESS;)